# Que diferencia tienen este tipo de cadenas en Python?

Tags: python

-La pregunta radica en lo siguiente... que diferencias hay entre los siguientes metodos de impresion de cadenas en python:

```
print(b'Dios no es bueno');

print(u'Dios no es bueno')
```

-Entiendo que print(f)  es para dar formato a las variables y que print(b) es para poner el texto literalmente (es decir en salida saldria `b'Dios no es bueno'` y no `'Dios no es Bueno'`) las preguntas son: ¿por que querria yo que se imprimiera mi cadena con una `b` por delante?, ¿para que es la u, ya que no percibo ninguna diferencia entre las salidas por pantalla?

Comment: Es que si una cadena está precedida por una b, no es una cadena, si no un objeto Bytes. Haría una respuesta más detallada, pero no se mucho sobre estos objetos.

Comment: Y la u CREO, no estoy seguro, se usa para hacer que la cadena sea de formato unicode.

Comment: Parcialmente correcto. Entiendo que se use esta web para hacer preguntas a las que no se encuentre respuesta, pero algo como esto es facil de buscar en la documentación: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: Si quieres que print() de python funcione como printf() de C, puedes usar .format: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

Es un lío porque la cosa ha cambiado de Python2 a Python3. Hoy día:

- No uses `u"cadena"`, sino directamente `"cadena"` para operar con cadenas de texto
- Usa `b"cadena"` para operar con cadenas de bytes
- Usa `.encode()`, `.decode()` para pasar de una a otra.

En los ejemplos que has puesto no hay diferencia entre poner u, b o nada, porque todos los caracteres usados en tu cadena son ASCII. Si aparecen caracteres de otros alfabetos sí habría diferencia. Para más detalles sigue leyendo.

### Tipos de cadenas

En Python hay dos tipos de cadenas, porque en el mundo real, en cierto sentido, también hay dos tipos de cadenas.

- Meras secuencias de bytes, sin significado "a priori". Esto es lo que podríamos encontrar si examinamos la memoria de un computador, por ejemplo. Veremos allí bytes, pero no sabremos si éstos son código máquina de instrucciones, o datos de tipo entero en binario, o datos de tipo float, o estructuras como objetos, o un color de un pixel, o texto,... Realmente un byte no significa nada a priori, el significado se lo da el programa que lo usa, según la forma en que lo use.

  Este tipo de secuencias de bytes se utilizan sobre todo en operaciones de entrada/salida. Es decir, cuando vuelcas algo a disco, o quieres enviar algo por la red, realmente volcarás o enviarás secuencias de bytes. Cuando lees algo del disco o recibes algo por la red, realmente recibirás secuencias de bytes. Por tanto Python usa este tipo de "cadenas" en estas operaciones.

  Otros lenguajes como C sólo tienen en realidad este tipo.
- Cadenas de texto. En este caso cada elemento de la cadena representa un carácter en algún idioma. Se pueden tener caracteres en cualquier idioma (chino, koreano, español, etc.) Obviamente este es el tipo apropiado cuando lo que queremos es procesar ese texto, con operaciones como pasarlo a mayúsculas, minúsculas, separar en palabras, contar cuántos caracteres tiene, etc...

El problema de tener dos tipos es que en algún momento hay que convertir uno en otro. Por ejemplo, si recibimos bytes de la red, pero sabemos que esos bytes representan en realidad caracteres, habrá que convertir la cadena de bytes en cadena de caracteres. A la inversa, si estamos trabajando en nuestro programa con texto pero queremos enviar ese texto por la red, habrá que convertirlo en cadenas de bytes.

### Python2

En **Python2**:

- Una cadena "normal", sin ninguna letra delante, como `"Hola mundo"` se consideraba una cadena de bytes. Cada uno de los bytes de esa cadena era simplemente los bytes que tu editor de texto hubiera volcado a disco cuando escribiste ese programa.

  Este tipo de cadenas también se podía escribir con una `b` delante, para remarcar que eran cadenas de bytes, pero era innecesario. `b"Hola"` era lo mismo que `"Hola"` a secas (esto ya no será así en Python3).
- Si querías una cadena de caracteres había que poner una `u` delante que indicaba "Unicode", que es un estándar de representación de caracteres en cualquier alfabeto.

Veamos un ejemplo. Supón que en tu programa escribes:

```
mensaje = "eñe"
print mensaje
```

Cuando guardes en disco este programa, tu editor tendrá que convertir el texto que has escrito (no solo el que está entre comillas, sino el código completo) a una secuencia de bytes. Para eso usará algún estándar de codificación. Según cuál sea tu editor y tu operativo usará un estándar u otro. Si estás en Windows probablemente usará `cp1252` y si estás en Linux o Mac probablemente sea `utf8`. Estos son mecanismos para convertir letras en bytes. A Python le da igual cuál hayas usado, pues si ejecutas el programa lo que contendrá la variable `mensaje` será simplemente la secuencia de bytes que el editor haya puesto entre comillas. Y el `print` se limitará a enviar esa secuencia de bytes a la terminal, la cual, si usa la misma codificación que usó el editor, lo mostrará correctamente.

Pero hay efectos secundarios un poco raros. Si imprimes `len(mensaje)` podrás encontrar que en algunas máquinas te da 3, y en otras 4. Esto depende del encoding que haya usado el editor al guardar, ya que por ejemplo si usó `cp1252` el carácter `ñ` se codifica con un byte, mientras que si usó `utf8` ese mismo carácter ocupa 2 bytes. Otro efecto secundario es que `mensaje.upper()` podría producir como resultado `"EñE"`, porque solo sabe pasar a mayúscula los bytes que sigan el estándar ASCII, y la ñ no está en ese estándar.

Por tanto lo correcto habría sido poner:

```
mensaje = u"eñe"
print mensaje
```

De este modo decimos que la cadena lo es *de caracteres* y ahora `len(mensaje)` dará correctamente 3 en todas las plataformas, y `mensaje.upper()` generará correctamente `"EÑE"`.

Pero aparece un nuevo problema, y es que, al igual que en el primer caso, el editor habrá guardado tu código con uno u otro encoding, por lo que a la hora en que python tenga que guardar la cadena como Unicode, necesitará saber qué encoding tiene el fichero, para saber cómo interpretar los bytes que ve dentro de las comillas y así poder convertirlos correctamente a unicode.

Esto se resolvía añdiendo en la primera línea del fichero un comentario como:

```
# coding: utf8
```

por ejemplo, donde en lugar `utf8` hay que poner la codificación que realmente haya usado tu editor.

Python2 además hacía conversiones implícitas de un tipo a otro. Es decir, si tratabas de volcar una cadena unicode a un dispositivo de entrada/salida, el propio python la convertía a cadena de bytes, usando un encoding que él mismo trataba de adivinar (y no siempre acertaba).

### Python3

En Python3 el tratamiento de cadenas cambia:

- Una cadena "normal", sin prefijo, se considera Unicode. Por tanto el prefijo `u` es redundante y no se usa ya.
- Si quieres una cadena de bytes tienes que poner `b` delante, pero entonces dentro de esa cadena sólo pueden aparecer caracteres ASCII, y si quieres meter cualquier otro byte debes usar la representación `\x` seguida de dos dígitos hexadecimales. Por ejemplo si queremos meter el byte de valor 41h pondríamos `"\x41"`. Pero como ese byte resulta ser el código ASCII de la A, también podríamos poner `"A"`. Por eso `b"Hola"` es una cadena de bytes válida, y equivalente a `b"\x48\x6f\x6c\x61"` (que son los códigos ascii de "H", "o", "l" y "a")

Además de esto:

- Si no se pone el comentario `# coding` al inicio del programa se asume por defecto utf8.
- No hay nunca conversiones implícitas de unicode a bytes. Si necesitas este tipo de transformación (típicamente en la E/S) tienes que hacerla tú específicamente mediante `.encode()` o `.decode()`. Hay una excepción y es cuando abres un fichero en modo texto con `open("fichero.txt")`. En ese caso puedes especificar el encoding del fichero (y si no lo especificas es utf8), y se admite entonces que leas o escribas directamente cadenas unicode (que recuerda, no llevan ya `u` delante), y éstas serán convertidas a bytes según el encoding especificado al abrir el fichero.

### Tus preguntas (python3)

- **¿por que querria yo que se imprimiera mi cadena con una b por delante?**

  La misión de `b"Hola"` no es que al imprimirla aparezca con una `b` por delante. Eso es un efecto secundario. Lo que ocurre es que al ser una cadena de bytes python3 elige mostrarla de ese modo, en lugar de enviarla "pura" a la terminal, pues eso podría causar salida de "basura" o incluso hacer que la terminal se cuelgue, según qué bytes pueda contener la cadena. (Por cierto que en Python2 no se toman esas precauciones y se vería simplemente `Hola` en vez de `b'Hola'`)

  Para imprir una cadena de bytes en pantalla, en Python3, tienes que convertirla en Unicode: `b"Hola".decode("ASCII")`. Eso implica que tienes que conocer qué codificación interna tiene esa secuencia de bytes. Naturalmente esto solo tiene sentido si tal secuencia de bytes representa texto, pero recuerda que una secuencia de bytes también puede ser una imagen jpg, un sonido mp3... cualquier cosa!
- **¿para que es la u, ya que no percibo ninguna diferencia entre las salidas por pantalla?**

  Como ya se dijo, en Python3 no hay diferencia entre poner una `u` delante o no ponerla (porque son lo mismo). Pero incluso en Python2 en que no eran lo mismo
  no notarías diferencia si la imprimes, pues ambas versiones de python a la hora de imprimir una cadena Unicode la convierten a bytes que la terminal pueda entender, y si han adivinado correctamente el encoding de la terminal, lo verás "normal", y más si el texto que muestras se compone solo de ASCII, pues este encoding es compatible con cualquier terminal.